# yup schema for boolean values (0 or 1)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, formik, yup

How can I modify my validation schema such that the entered value is boolean, either 1 or 0? not true false etc

```
  formValue: Yup.number()
        .boolean()
        .typeError('boo'),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `test` method .

```
formValue: Yup.number().test('is boolean',
  'Please enter either 1 or 0',
  (value) => value === 0 || value === 1)
```

[Yup - test](https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedtestname-string-message-string--function-test-function-schema)